# List handling and random number generation in Erlang

Tags: random, erlang

Why do I get a list of identical numbers when I run `randy:spawner()` below? I was  expecting a list of random numbers. How could I change the code to achieve this?

```
-module(randy).
-export([randlister/2,spawner/0]).
-import(lists,[map/2]).

spawner() ->
    [spawn(fun() -> randlister(X,random:uniform()) end) || X <- lists:seq(1,3)].


randlister(X, Randomnumber) ->
io:format("~p,    ~p~n",[X,Randomnumber]).
```

Example output:

```
18> randy:spawner().
1,    0.4435846174457203
2,    0.4435846174457203
3,    0.4435846174457203
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must seed the random number generator in each process:

```
spawner() ->
    [spawn(fun() ->
                   random:seed(now()),
                   randlister(X,random:uniform())
           end) || X <- lists:seq(1,3)].
```

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318156/how-to-create-a-list-of-1000-random-number-in-erlang/10319823#10319823)

Answer (score 2):

#### Why do I get a list of identical numbers when I run `randy:spawner()` below?

You **must** seed before generating random numbers.
Random number sequences generated from the same seed will be exactly the same.

If a process calls `uniform/0` or `uniform/1` without setting a seed first, [`seed/0`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/random.html#seed-0) is called automatically.
`seed/0` will seed random number generation with a **default (fixed)** value,
which can be accessed through [`seed0/0`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/random.html#seed0-0). On my laptop it always returns `{3172,9814,20125}` with a default process dictionary.

#### How could I change the code to achieve this?

In the simplest case, the solution from @EmilVikström is sufficient.
However, I do recommend to keep track of the random number generation **state** 
so you can have a easier life when you're debugging.

[A random number generation state](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/random.html#type-ran) is just a 3-tuple of integers, as returned by `now()`. The seed is just the first state. Then you can use [`uniform_s/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/random.html#uniform_s-1) or [`uniform_s/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/random.html#uniform_s-2) to generate random numbers from specified states.

By using these functions with states, you can specify random number seeds **outside** your Erlang code, e.g. passing a seed through command-line options or environment variables.

- When you are testing/debugging, fix the seed so that each time you run your program will give the same result.
- When you are satisfied, change the seed in order to (probably) continue debugging :-)
- When you are ready for production, just pass the current time (or whatever) as the seed, so you can have some randomness.