# Restricting number of function iterations

Tags: erlang

I'm writing a code in Erlang which suppose to generate a random number for a random amount of time and add each number to a list. I managed a function which can generate random numbers and i kinda managed a method for adding it to a list,but my main problem is restricting the number of iterations of the function. I like the function to produce several numbers and add them to the list and then kill that process or something like that.
Here is my code so far:

```
generator(L1)->
random:seed(now()),
A = random:uniform(100),
L2 = lists:append(L1,A),
generator(L2),

producer(B,L) ->

receive
  {last_element} ->
   consumer ! {lists:droplast(B)}
end

consumer()->
 timer:send_after(random:uniform(1000),producer,{last_element,self()}),
receive
  {Answer, Producer_PID} ->
  io:format("the last item is:~w~n",[Answer])
end,
consumer().



start() ->

register(consumer,spawn(lis,consumer,[])),
register(producer,spawn(lis,producer,[])),
register(generator,spawn(lis,generator,[random:uniform(10)])).
```

I know it's a little bit sloppy and incomplete but that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use [`rand`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rand.html) to generate random numbers instead of `random`, it is an improved module.

In addition, when using `rand:uniform/1` you won't need to change the seed every time you run your program. From erlang documentation:

> If a process calls `uniform/0` or `uniform/1` without setting a seed
>   first, `seed/1` is called automatically with the default algorithm and
>   creates a non-constant seed.

Finally, in order to create a list of random numbers, take a look at [How to create a list of 1000 random number in erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318156/how-to-create-a-list-of-1000-random-number-in-erlang).

If I conclude all this, you can just do:

```
[rand:uniform(100) || _ <- lists:seq(1, 1000)].
```

Answer (score 1):

There have some issue in your code:

1. `timer:send_after(random:uniform(1000),producer,{last_element,self()}),`, you send `{last_element,self()}` to `producer` process, but in `producer`, you just receive `{last_element}`, these messages are not matched.

you can change

```
producer(B,L) ->
    receive
        {last_element} ->
            consumer ! {lists:droplast(B)}
    end.
```

to

```
producer(B,L) ->
    receive
         {last_element, FromPid} ->
             FromPid! {lists:droplast(B)}
    end.
```

the same reason for `consumer ! {lists:droplast(B)}` and `{Answer, Producer_PID} ->`.